# output text not showing value in bean - JSF page

Tags: java, jsf, javabeans

There **poll** event on my jsf page which calls a pool event. There is a variable called **i** with getters and setters and i want to show the value of i on the page. each time the bean is called by the poll event the **value of i changes**. so I tried using the below code on my jsf page but its not showing any value. Any idea of wat i am doing wrong?

```
af:outputText value="#{UserChoiceInput.i}" id="ot1"

Bean()
{
```

private string i ;//edited

```
public void callPollTimer(PollEvent pollEvent)

{

//code for changing value of i

}
  public void seti(String i) {

    this.counti = i;

  }

  public String geti() {

    return i;

  }

}
```

Faces-config

```
<managed-bean id="__2"> 
  <managed-bean-name>UserChoiceInput</managed-bean-name> 
  <managed-bean-class>oracle.insurance.viking.questionnaire.view.backing.UserChoic‌eInput</managed-bean-class> 
  <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope> 
</managed-bean>
```

Comment: Can you show your JSP code and faces-config.xml here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to partial refresh the component(OutputText component) after assigning the value to the component pro-grammatically  that's why it was not rendering.

Answer (score 1):

The methods must be named `setI(String i)` and `getI()` - with uppercase I - to be recognized as getter/setter.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class UserChoiceInput {
    private String i;

    public void callPollTimer(PollEvent pollEvent) {
        //code for changing value of i
    }

    public void setI(String i) {
        this.counti = i;
    }

    public String getI() {
        return i;
    }
}
```

Try with this. you have to declare variable in UserChoiceInput Bean class

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add.. There is a variable in the bean.. Its still nt wrking

Comment: look carefully in faces-config.xml file, you have to correctly declare the userChoiceInput Bean.

Comment: Its is declared and getting accessed. I am printing out value of i using system out and its showing correct value each time .